# Responsive fixed sliding slide-bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap I have created a sidebar. In the beginning only the font-awesome icon is displayed and on hover it moves to the left which makes other portion visible.

**Problem:** It is not responsive at all. (My be because I am doing it completely wrong)

I want only the font-awesome icon to be displayed before hover on any size screen.

Expected output on all screen sizes:

[image]

```css
.sidebar-fixed-right {
    top: 20rem;
    right: -20.2%;
    position: fixed;
    transition-property: right;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right:hover {
    right: -10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.sidebar-text {
    padding-left: 1.2rem;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right sidebar-fixed-right">
    <div class="widget" style="width:20rem">
        <div class="widget-content widget-content-full">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a class="nodecoration" href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" style="vertical-align: middle;color: #EF5350;">
                                </i>
                                <span class="sidebar-text">Hello There</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it compulsory to use table ??

Comment: No it isn't compulsory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated version your code,

```css
html,body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;

}

.sidebar-fixed-right {
    top:100px;
    right:-100px;
    position: fixed;
    transition-property: right;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right:hover {
    right:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
.sidebar-text {
    padding-left: 1.2rem;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right sidebar-fixed-right">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-content widget-content-full">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a class="nodecoration" href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" style="vertical-align: middle;color: #EF5350;">
                                </i>
                                <span class="sidebar-text">Hello There</span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

A simplified version with dynamic width.

Using `transform:translate(100%, 0);` will hide full element, then set `right:35px;` or whatever area/size of *sliding slide-bar* you want to show.

```css
.sidenav {
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  right:35px;
  top: 70px;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform:translate(100%, 0);
}

.sidenav:hover {
  right: 0;
  transform:translate(0);
}

.fa {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #EF5350;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="sidenav">
  <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
  <span class="sidebar-text">Hello There</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank-you for your answer and  explanation :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `px` instead of percentage `%` values,

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right {
  top: 20rem;
  right: -180px;
  position: fixed;
  transition-property: right;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right:hover {
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.sidebar-text {
  padding-left: 1.2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-3 pull-right sidebar-fixed-right">
  <div class="widget" style="width:20rem">
    <div class="widget-content widget-content-full">
      <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a class="nodecoration" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" style="vertical-align: middle;color: #EF5350;">
                                </i>
                <span class="sidebar-text">Hello There</span>
              </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The responsiveness problem rises from the use of %.

Just move it to the right a fixed amount.

```
.sidebar-fixed-right {
    right: -210px;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right:hover {
    right: -70px;
}
```

These seemed to work. Also watch out for the container in which it is placed.

```
html, body {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Intresting..., I would Try something like this.

Instead of **Percentages** use **Pixels** as **@Cătălin Costan** said.

CSS

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
i.fa-stack-overflow{
  color:#EF5350;
}

.sidebar-fixed-right{
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  right:-80px;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
.sidebar-fixed-right:hover{
  right:0px;
}

.widget{
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding:5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="sidebar-fixed-right">
  <div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-content widget-content-full">
      <a class="nodecoration" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-text">Hello There</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/vbrLsbu5/3/)

Hope this Helps..